# Use group by in and return identity of the row

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

For this table...

```
id  type   food     price 
--------------------------
1   veg    carrot   10    
2   veg    turnip   11
3   fruit  bramble  6
4   fruit  rasp     4
5   fruit  current  9
...
```

I can return the max price of the most expensive food for each food type like this...

```
select max(price) from tableName group by type;
```

But I'd like to return the id number of each row that contains the most expensive food for each food type. And return one and only one row per food type. Ie return this....

```
id  
----
2
5 
...
```

This is a simplified version of my real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM ( SELECT id, type
       FROM table
       ORDER BY price DESC) AS h
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Thanks. This indeed worked after a bit of modification: 
SELECT id
FROM ( SELECT type, id
       FROM tableName
       ORDER BY price DESC) as tbl1
GROUP BY type

Comment: However, as the above relies on mysql choosing the first entry in the group, I'm not sure if this is very reliable as it says in the MySql documentation...
"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to declare the table :) When grouping by, it has as default the first row. In this case the sorted row by price desc. I have never seen an other behavior then this.

Comment: You can change that to `ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1` to make it clear that you only want the first row.

Comment: @Derobert: it doesn't work. Then only one row in total would be taken. Not 2 as in the example.

Comment: @Robin Castlin: Sorry, you are correct, I should have read the query more closely.

Comment: using GROUP BY without an aggregate function makes mysql choose the first row it encounters, which is unpredictable

Comment: Which in this case first encounters the row sorted by price DESC? Note that I'm using GROUP BY after ORDER BY, and not before.

Comment: That doesn't matter. From the mysql docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses."

Comment: What an odd behavior of MySQL. How come it's functional like that, and how come I have always received the first row every time I've used this method so far?

Comment: "Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses." I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, that they simply state that an ORDER BY after GROUP BY may not worked as you may want and they simply say that it chooses freely to warn people of the risks of using GROUP BY. I don't see any logic in the server to pick the value by random instead of in order.

Comment: That's true, there's no logic to choose a random value, it simply chooses the first value it comes across. The point made in the documentation is that we cannot determine which value it chooses, although it chooses the same value for every execution of the query. Given this context, i'm trying to verify your claim that it selects the first row of any group as default.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(id) from
(SELECT t1.* FROM tableName t1 
JOIN (SELECT type, max(price) AS price FROM tableName GROUP BY type) t2 
ON t2.type = t1.type AND t2.price = t1.price) t3
GROUP BY userId;
```

Comment: Correction. It doesnt work. If two food types have the same price it will return more than two rows. I need just one row per food type.

Comment: Do you mean having rows like (2,veg,turnip,11), (3,veg,turnip,11), (4,veg,turnip,11) and so on? If so then now what's the criteria for deciding which id to select? If any will do, then you can just run a select max ... group by on the above query.

Comment: Yes. If there are more than one veg of the same price and type, then I want it to return just one - the first one mySQL comes across will do. This might seem a bit odd for the example, but I wanted to present a simple example and in my real project it makes sense.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "If any will do, then you can just run a select max ... group by on the above query" Do you mean like the mySQL statement I've shown in my question? This returns the max price but I want the identity of the row that contains the max price for each food type.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect what i was talking about, although now the query seems to have become too unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

This horrible query will work when more food have the same type and price.
I would hardly ever use this in production as this is unmaintainable.

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id 
FROM (
    SELECT t.id AS id, t.type
    FROM tableName t
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(price) AS m, type
        FROM tableName 
        GROUP BY type
    ) sub 
        ON sub.m=t.price AND sub.type=t.type
    ORDER BY id
) whatever
GROUP BY type
```