# Group by user and show latest in MYSQL not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a social network I am coding but it's a bit different than others, in this case there is only ever one status show per user on a feed section.

So I need to sort the status by date with the latest ones on top but also group by the userID
unfortunately I can't seem to get this working....

This is my current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM status
WHERE userID != "83" #This is just so my statuses don't show
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY addedDate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I expect to see the latest status results and only one per user instead I see the first statuses so the group by is working but not the order by.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to [Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550415/623041), that approach is unreliable because MySQL does not guarantee that it will always return the most recent status from each group.  You must instead join your table with a subquery that selects the most recent status (based on `addedDate`).

```
SELECT   *
FROM     status
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT   userID, MAX(addedDate) as addedDate
    FROM     status
    GROUP BY userID
  ) AS mostRecent
ORDER BY addedDate DESC
LIMIT    10
```

Note that if a user has multiple status updates with the same `addedDate`, the server will return all of them (whereas Robin's query would return an indeterminate one); if you need control over such a situation, you will need to define how one determines which such status update should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *
        FROM status
        WHERE userID != "83"
        ORDER BY addedDate DESC) AS h
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY addedDate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You must ORDER BY before GROUP BY'ing.

[**Example 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497635/how-to-write-inner-query-that-returns-latest-message-for-a-given-user/10497700#10497700)
[**Example 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436973/use-group-by-in-mysql-and-return-identity-of-the-row/7437076#7437076)

Comment: From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html): "*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate*".

Comment: I've had this discussion endless times. This solution is reliable. Let me see if I can dig out a previous answer of mines regarding this.

Comment: That's working, but not entirely, there is one post showing in the wrong position in terms of date order. Would it be because of the group by user ID?

Comment: Add desired ORDER BY before `LIMIT 10`. @eggyal please check **Example 2**'s comments.

Comment: @RobinCastlin: Those comments only reaffirm my point - the values chosen are *indeterminate*.  You are relying on MySQL to always choose the first from the order returned by the subquery (and indeed, I've only ever seen it do that), but that behaviour is not defined and **you cannot rely on it**.

Comment: I've supplied this answer countless times and **none** have mentioned any problems with it. Just because there is no promise that something works, it doesn't mean it can't. What other way would you say it chooses values by then the 1st occurence?

Comment: @RobinCastlin: Just because it has always worked up to now, does not mean that it will always work in the future... the fact that the manual explicitly states that the values are indeterminate is about as close as the developers could get to advising you not to do this without them commenting on this post in person.  In other RDBMS, the query would not even be legal: MySQL only permits it for performance.

Comment: What new logic would be implemented in MySQL that would pick something else then the 1st rows values and still maintain the simple useage of GROUP BY? I understand your concerns, but I fail to see much danger from using this method.

Comment: @RobinCastlin: Such speculation is outside the scope of this discussion; but nevertheless an example: results might be grouped using a hash index, resulting in very much unordered results within the group.

Comment: Good example. However that would mean that the query would ignore a ORDER BY, even though that command still exists and wishes to be followed. I surely hope MySQL always lets me do what I wish to do, point me to how I can do it better and more optimize friendly and not asume that my commands are pointless and should be ignored. Thanks for your input. I will stick with this solution until I find a better and/or easier one.

Comment: @RobinCastlin: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10551071/623041) for an alternative that does not rely on this indeterminate behaviour.  And no, it doesn't mean that MySQL ignored the `ORDER BY` in your subquery - the results of that subquery would indeed be ordered - it's the *grouping* operation in the *parent* query that could be performed using a hash index and therefore give rise to unordered records within each group.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userID, max(addedDate)
FROM status
WHERE userID != "83" #This is just so my statuses don't show
GROUP BY userID
```