# Sort grouped rows in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database with the following structure:

**Table `customers`:**

- id (int)
- name (string)
- ...

**Table `orders`:**

- id (int)
- customerID (int)
- timestamp_unix (int)
- title

Now I want to select all customers as well as their latest order. I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.timestamp_unix, b.title FROM customers AS a JOIN orders AS b ON a.id = b.customerID GROUP BY a.id
```

This works fine except that I don't get the *latest* order (and its title) but the first one that has been inserted to the database as the first one.

So how can I get the latest order (highest `id` and highest `timestamp_unix`)? For the timestamp only, I could just use `MAX(b.timestamp_unix)` but how do I get the matching `b.title`?

Thank you!

Comment: how about order directly by timestamp_unix ? the latest (highest id) inserted will be on top... what am i missing?

Comment: No, of course, this is not possible. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking here ;) Please see my comment to philwinkle's answer for more details.

Comment: Okay, as he has deleted his answer now: Just using `ORDER BY` is not possible as the rows are already grouped when coming to the `ORDER BY` directive and so MySQL picks one row of each group arbitrarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pls try this one, I have tested it well.

`SELECT a.name as 'Customer Name', b.title as 'Order Title' FROM customers a, orders b where a.id=b.customerID AND b.timestamp_unix=(Select max(c.timestamp_unix) from orders c where c.customerID=a.id) GROUP BY a.id`

Comment: Thank you very much! As your query is a bit faster, yours is the best one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.timestamp_unix, b.title 
FROM customers AS a 
JOIN (  SELECT customerID, timestamp_unix, title
        FROM orders
        ORDER BY timestamp_unix DESC) AS b
ON a.id = b.customerID 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY timestamp_unix DESC
```

[Read this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550386/group-by-user-and-show-latest-in-mysql-not-working/10550415#answer-10551071)

As mentioned in refered question, there are at least 2 approaches to solve this matter. Choose the one you find safiest and easiest.

Comment: Shouldn't there be no grouping and a limit on the subquery to only provide the latest order?

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine but the query is quite slow, right? It doesn't use any indexes (at least for me). Can't it be optimized in some way?

Comment: Do you have any WHERE case? Try inserting it after `FROM orders`. And an index on timestamp_unix would speed this up.

Comment: This doesn't help, although I just used your query without any additions: http://i45.tinypic.com/4kbvbt.png

Comment: Please see Pritom's query, it is a bit faster as it is able to use the indexes better. You can try it yourself ;) Nevertheless, thank you very much for your correct and helpful answer!

Comment: It's a shame that query won't handle multiple maxed timestamp_unix though correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a subselect, do your join but take the grouping away, then make this what you join on

```
 Left join (select orderid from orders where customerid = A.customerid order by orderdate desc limit 1) as lastorder
```

I'd like to be more clear but I'm on my mobile haha

Here I'm on my pc now, here's a MSSQL fiddle to show it - just convert to Mysql (Syntax should be the same apart from the TOP 1 should be a LIMIT 1 at the end instead)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29a3c/13

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks good in your example, but MySQL doesn't support it, unfortunately :( `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Ah must be a version thing I'm sure it's worked in my sql before! Oh well sorry couldn't help

Comment: No problem ;) Which version did you use then? `SELECT VERSION()` returns `5.5.22-1~dotdeb.0-log` for me.

Comment: Would have been an enterprise version